# Spring-Data Gemfire - Random Threadshift error

Tags: gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

We're seeing a strange error while running Integration tests (with embedded Gemfire server). Retry of the failing tests fixes itself.

Is there any configuration / setting missing which is causing this issue?

Gemfire 8.1.0

```
java.lang.AssertionError: null
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.ha.ThreadIdentifier$Bits.shift(ThreadIdentifier.java:119)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.ha.ThreadIdentifier$WanType.generateWanId(ThreadIdentifier.java:67)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.ha.ThreadIdentifier.createFakeThreadIDForParallelGSPrimaryBucket(ThreadIdentifier.java:281)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.wan.serial.SerialGatewaySenderImpl.setModifiedEventId(SerialGatewaySenderImpl.java:251)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.wan.AbstractGatewaySender.distribute(AbstractGatewaySender.java:917)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.LocalRegion.notifyGatewayHubs(LocalRegion.java:6429)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.LocalRegion.basicPutPart2(LocalRegion.java:5982)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.AbstractRegionMap.basicPut(AbstractRegionMap.java:2930)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.LocalRegion.virtualPut(LocalRegion.java:5800)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.DistributedRegion.virtualPut(DistributedRegion.java:386)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.LocalRegionDataView.putEntry(LocalRegionDataView.java:118)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.LocalRegion.basicPut(LocalRegion.java:5190)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.LocalRegion.validatedPut(LocalRegion.java:1581)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.LocalRegion.put(LocalRegion.java:1564)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.AbstractRegion.put(AbstractRegion.java:327)
```

Comment: Hmm, I have never seen this error before (not even in the SDG test suite), but it is definitely coming from GemFire and is not necessarily caused by SDG (meaning, if you were to do the exact same test setup using GemFire's API with no SDG involved, I would expect to see the same error).   Perhaps you could share a bit of code illustrating the setup/teardown of your embedded GemFire instance?  A stack trace alone is not enough in this case to pin point the cause.  What version of SDG are you using?

Comment: Were you able to find the cause of the error. I am facing the same error using gemfire-8.2.0 which happens on our CI server (Linux) but not on local machines (Windows).